# I get a contextTypes error when I try to test a very simple component

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, expectj

I am new to reactjs and trying to write a unit test for a simple function. 
I am using enzyme and here is my test:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import {P} from "../../src/app/components/T";
import ToDoItem from "../../src/app/components/ToDoItem";

function mockItem(overrides) {
  // … create mock ToDo Item
}

describe('<P />', () => {
  it('renders without exploding', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<P attach={ true } />);
    expect(wrapper.length).toEqual(1);
  });
});
```

and here is my component:

```
import  React from "react";

export class T extends  React.Component{
  render() {
    return (
    <div>
        <div className="row panel">
            <div className="col-sm-12 header">uuuuu</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
}
```

But when I run it I get the following error:

```
<P /> renders without exploding:
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'contextTypes' of undefined
  at ShallowComponentWrapper._maskContext (node_modules\react-dom\lib\ReactCompositeComponent.js:461:33)
  at ShallowComponentWrapper._processContext (node_modules\react-dom\lib\ReactCompositeComponent.js:481:30)
  at ShallowComponentWrapper.mountComponent (node_modules\react-dom\lib\ReactCompositeComponent.js:180:30)
  at Object.mountComponent (node_modules\react-dom\lib\ReactReconciler.js:46:35)
  at ReactShallowRenderer._render (node_modules\react-dom\lib\ReactShallowRenderer.js:126:23)
  at _batchedRender (node_modules\react-dom\lib\ReactShallowRenderer.js:79:12)
  at Object.batchedUpdates (node_modules\react-dom\lib\ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:60:14)
  at Object.batchedUpdates (node_modules\react-dom\lib\ReactUpdates.js:97:27)
  at ReactShallowRenderer.render (node_modules\react-dom\lib\ReactShallowRenderer.js:106:18)
  at ReactShallowRenderer.render (node_modules\enzyme\build\react-compat.js:158:39)
  at node_modules\enzyme\build\ShallowWrapper.js:90:26
  at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.perform (node_modules\react-dom\lib\Transaction.js:140:20)
  at Object.batchedUpdates (node_modules\react-dom\lib\ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62:26)
  at batchedUpdates (node_modules\react-dom\lib\ReactUpdates.js:97:27)
  at node_modules\enzyme\build\ShallowWrapper.js:89:41
  at withSetStateAllowed (node_modules\enzyme\build\Utils.js:224:3)
  at new ShallowWrapper (node_modules\enzyme\build\ShallowWrapper.js:88:38)
  at shallow (node_modules\enzyme\build\shallow.js:19:10)
  at Context.<anonymous> (C:/tj/reactjs-basics/test/components/test.js:16:25)
```

I do not know if I am missing any library or if I am doing something wring in my code. Can anyone help?

Comment: You are not defined any `contextTypes` in your component and passing a context object `{ attach: true}`  remove that. it  should work

Comment: @mshameer I first tried it without that and no result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are importing `P` component in a wrong way.So if you

```
export class T extends  React.Component{}
```

Then import should be

```
import { T } from "../../src/app/components/T";
...
shallow(<T attach={ true } />);
```

Take a look at this [**`article`**](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html) it will be useful for you.

HTH

Comment: @HamedMinaee you dont have `P` component, it should be `T` as i did it in my asnwer, or rename your class name to `P`

Comment: Yes you are right and thanks a lot for your helpful answer

Comment: @HamedMinaee does it help you?

Comment: A question : so when I have to import my own component I should put it in {} . am I right?

Comment: @HamedMinaee take a look at link which i provided in answer, there is all cases how to use it in a right way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the line

```
const wrapper = shallow(<P/>, { attach: true });
```

but per Enzymes documentation (http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html) the second argument to shallow should be an object with a context to pass down to the component.

If you are instead trying to pass that as a prop into your component, you should write the shallow declaration like this:

```
const wrapper = shallow(<P attach={ true } />);
```

Comment: Thanks Ben, I added that line and I updated my code above, but still the same issue